# jQuery set select box to empty option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is the jQuery code that I am using which helps me in getting the values for a select box I need when I change the first select box.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").change(function(){
      $('.quantity').val('');
      $('#trblock').fadeIn();
      if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
      }
      var id = $(this).val();
      var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
      $('#select2').html('<option value="">').append(options);
    });
});
```

What happens here is that whenever I change the select box value from 1st select box I get some values in the second select box. But when I roll back to the previously selected option in the 1st text box I find that the 2nd select box is already showing the options which I selected previously. What I want is whenever I change selecting the 1st select box option the 2nd select box should start with a blank option like `<option value=""></option>` instead of the previously selected option in 2nd select box.

To make it easy I roll it in points.

1. Selected an option in 1st select box example "Animals".

   `<select name="" id="select1">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="1">Animals</option>
       <option value="2">Games</option>
       <option value="3">Fruits</option>
   </select>`
2. Got some values in 2nd select box.

   `<select name="" id="select2">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="1">Cat</option>
       <option value="2">Dog</option>
       <option value="3">Monkey</option>
   </select>`
3. Selected a value from the 2nd select box example "Dog".
4. Then I thought to switch the selection from 1st select box so I selected "Fruits".
5. Got some values in 2nd select box.

   `<select name="" id="select2">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="1">Apple</option>
       <option value="2">Banana</option>
       <option value="3">Grapes</option>
   </select>`
6. I selected grapes this time. Ok, fine till here.
7. But then if I again change my 1st selection to animals I should get the 2nd select box to start with the empty option (blank field) but Instead it starts with the previously selected "Dog". This is what I DO NOT want. Each time I change selecting the option from 1st select box I want second select box to start with the blank option field so that I can again choose from the full list i.e., "Cat", "Dog", "Monkey".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `$('#select2').val('')` at the last of `select1`'s change event like following.

```
$("#select1").change(function () {
    $('.quantity').val('');
    $('#trblock').fadeIn();
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html('<option value="">').append(options);

    $('#select2').val(''); //add this line
});
```

Comment: already tried... in fact.. this was the 1st thing that came in my mind.. but this did not help :(

Comment: "did not help" is not useful.  What happened?  Do you have an error in your error log?  This answer is corrects I I'm guessing your implementation of the solution is the problem.  Edit your question showing how you tried to implement this, so we can see / help

Comment: sorry brother.. I was wrong.. THIS WORKED FOR ME NOW.. I had put this in 3rd line after  $('.quantity').val(''); maybe this is why it did not work.. but after placing where you said it worked.. thanks bro.. :)

Comment: you are right @cale_b.. I implemented the same code b4 but the placement was wrong.. now rectified and working... thanks to Azim